# unexpected T_CONCAT_EQUAL

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I'm getting an unexpected T_CONCAT_EQUAL error on a line of the following form:

```
$arg1 .= "arg2".$arg3."arg4";
```

I'm using PHP5.  I could simply go an do the following:

```
$arg1 = $arg1."arg2".$arg3."arg4";
```

but I'd like to know whats going wrong in the first place.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
sweeney

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would happen when $arg1 is undefined (doesn't have a value, was never set.)

Comment: bingo - turns out i left the $ off of $arg1.  not sure why it didnt catch the T_VAR first but close enough.  thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

So the most accurate reason is that the above posted line of code:

```
$arg1 .= "arg2".$arg3."arg4";
```

was actually as follows in my source:

```
arg1 .= "arg2".$arg3."arg4";
```

The $ was missing from arg1.  I dont know why the interpreter did not catch that first, but whatever.  Thanks for the input Jeremy and Bailey - it lead me right to the problem.

Comment: When the interpreter comes across something like 'arg1' without quotes or anything, first it checks if it's a defined constant, and if it isn't, it interprets it as the string 'arg1'. So you got the error because it couldn't assign a value to a constant string.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you forgot a semicolon on the line above this one.